# Does creating multiple tpl files affect site performance?

Tags: theming

I am creating different tpl file for each and every content type. (Including every view)

Is it a good practice? And does it affect site performance?

Any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It won't make a noticeable difference as long as you disable rebuilding the theme registry on production, enable caching, and follow best practices (e.g. don't execute logic or queries in your templates, and never ever save PHP code in the database). There are quite a few other, more noticeable things you can tweak to improve performance and load time before you get to the level of worrying about the number of templates.

Comment: actually i usually create page tpl instead of node tpls, it is also a good practice ? i mean in all page tpls the header, footer, menu are being repeated but in node tpls they dont. And thanks for the other suggestions :)

Comment: It depends on whether you're trying to change the output of the whole page or just each node. A page can have multiple nodes, or no node at all. You should use the type of tpl that targets the level of specificity that you want.

Answer (score 0):

That level of theming is something I've tried to move away from as it can get quite messy in terms of organisation.  Also I believe there is a performance hit for loading a lot of templates - this below is specific to `field.tpl.php` but clearly applies more widely:

> However, it takes longer for the server to process templates than to call a function, so for websites with many fields displayed on a page, this can result in a noticeable slowdown of the website.

[theme_field Drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7)

But like @betherwisser says there will be a lot of other things you can look at first.

To summarise: for content types I would think twice about going the tpl route because the Drupal 7 display options are generally powerful enough with a few tweaks in preprocess functions, that way the display is kept in the CMS which makes it more accessible and you avoid the performance hit (however marginal).

Views though I'd probably template as they can be a pain to get looking right any other way, though I'd always try to start with a preprocess function in template.php as it can be really hard to wade through a load of views `tpl` files to find the one that is actually relevant.

Comment: I don't agree with your advice regarding node tpl's. I have seen many designs that could not be easily implemented using the standard display options. If you want to avoid node tpl's, you quickly end up using modules like Panels and/or Display Suite. Those modules are awesome if they fit your use case, but in my experience tpl files are straightforward, flexible and easy to understand for others (including yourself 3 months from now :-)).

Comment: Tpls for each nodetype doesn't seem extreme to me at all. Now, for specific nodes by ID, it's true that templates that specific should be avoided. Also your point about field templates is valid, although it would only apply during cache rebuild.

Comment: @marcvangend Panels essentially just takes over different levels of theming from templates. And if you use style plugins, they have their own templates. Panels are great for a lot of things but "to avoid tpls" is not a good reason to use them.

Comment: @betherwisser I didn't say one should avoid tpl's in the first place. I was merely reacting to the advice to "think twice about tpl's because Drupal 7 display options are generally powerful enough".

Comment: @marcvangend - I don't think you should not use templates I I just don't think it should be the default approach. Personally I find that doing some field level theming in conjunction with with the display options provides a structured and flexible approach for the sites I'm called on to build - just providing an alternate view.